# adding new subtasks div in task div using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

this is another post of mine related to the same app that i am developing.I have certain tasks div which are created by embeded ruby in html file,so by fetching the task from my db,with every task a new div is created having the id="tasks".Now those tasks hav subtasks in them and a add button,to add a subtask.Wat i need now is that when i click on add button it should append a new p id="subtask" but only in that task container whose add button was clicked.Right now it adds to the first task container,whether i click on the second task or third task.I am adding new subtasks dynamically using jquery.

Here is the code that i am using

```
<div class="user span9 default-skin">
<ul>
    <% if @project.tasks.any? %>
        <% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>

        <div class="span5" id="tasks">
            <div id="addtaskdiv">

            <p><b><%=task.taskname %></b>
            <%=link_to 'edit name',edit_task_path(task) %></p>

            <% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>


                <p id="subtask" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><%=subtask.name %></p>
                <%end%>

                <%=render 'layouts/modal' %>
                </div>

                <p id="addcard"><a href="#">Add a card...</a></p>
        </div>

    <%end%>
<%end%>


</ul>


</div>
```

and here is the jquery code which appends new p id="subtask"

```
   $("#addcard > a").click(function(){
    $('#addtaskdiv').append("<p id='subtask'></p>");
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, with your code that shows the tasks list you end up having more `div` elements with the same `ID` on the page, that is wrong, `id` should be unique, you can have more `div` elements with the same `class` not `id`.

so you need to do smoethig like this:

```
<div class="span5" id="tasks_<%= task.id %>">
```

that will output something like:

```
<div class="span5" id="tasks_5">
...
<div class="span5" id="tasks_6">
...
<div class="span5" id="tasks_7">
...
```

the same for `addtaskdiv` and `addcard` divs.

having different ids you will be able to get the unique element on page with jquery to append the `<p id='subtask'></p>` to desired element by ID. Right now it goes to first cause you have allof them wiht the same ID and it appends to first one that was found.

```
 $("#addcard_5 > a").click(function(){
   $('#addtaskdiv_5').append("<p id='subtask'></p>");
 });
```

5 in the example above is a variable that will change depending on what button you'll press.

**Update**

> how will u get the card id in jquery?

```
<a href="#" data-id='<%= task.id %>'>Add a card...</a>
```

wil generate html: `<a href="#" data-id='5'>Add a card...</a>` and jquery code will look something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('#addtaskdiv_' + $(this).data('id')).append("<p id='subtask'></p>");
});
```

Comment: how will u get the card id in jquery and will using the common class names instead of common id help??as suggested by the person in the above comment

Comment: Thank u so much,ur code worked perfectly fr me.Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: rmagnum,can u help me with now rendering my new subtask form at the place where the new p id="subtask" is getting added.Basically in the original app when the add button is clicked the form for creating the new subtask should be added and on clicking the save button it should send that form to my subtask create controller

Comment: for this things you better use ajax, but it's too much to explain in a comment.

Comment: yes thank fr replien,i figured out another way of doin it.I am using jquery fr it only and the div will be hidden,itgets displayed only when the user click on add button.So this way works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

from the behavior it appears you have duplicate ids in the dom. so please keep common classname rather than giving id. Then using classname your code should be.

```
  $(".addcard > a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.addtaskdiv').append("<p id='subtask'></p>");
  });
```